# How to convert mixed string to bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, hex

I have a representation of a bytes which I want to convert into actual bytes.

e.g. notice the double-backslash, I'm working with a literal backslash, x and 2-digit hex:

```
>>> foo=rb"foo\x00"
>>> foo
b'foo\\x00'
```

eval() will do it, but it's a terrible thing to do:

```
>>> eval(b"b\"" + foo + b"\"")
b'foo\x00'
```

I've looked at binascii and I don't see a method to convert this kind of data.  What is this encoding called?

Short of writing my own routine to do this, is there an easier way?

Comment: You already have the bytes. Just write it to a file, and read with an hex-editor. On prompt and on terminal python will write you a representation (as escape) of characters that cannot be printed. '\x00' is one of such character.

Comment: It needs to be done programmatically, hoping to find an elegant Python 3 way to do this.   Seems improbable that I should have to hand-craft it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following code snippet could help:

```
foo = rb'foo\x00'
bar = eval(repr(foo).replace('\\\\','\\'))
for x in bar:
    print(x, type(x))
```

> ```
> 102 <class 'int'>
> 111 <class 'int'>
> 111 <class 'int'>
> 0 <class 'int'>
> ```